# Laravel Eloquent Runs two queries on update?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was curious to know, if laravel eloquent runs only one query on updating a row. So I tried the following

```
Route::get('/cli', function(){
   DB::enableQueryLog();

   $client = Client::findOrFail(1);
   $client->first_name = 'Noob';
   $client->save();
   return response()->json([
       'client' => $client->first_name,
       'query' => DB::getQueryLog()
   ], 200);
});
```

This gave me the following result

```
{
     "client": "Noob",
     "query": [{
                 "query": "select * from `clients` where `clients`.`id` = ? limit 1",
     "bindings": [
           1
        ],
     "time": 0.71
},
{
      "query": "update `clients` set `first_name` = ?, `updated_at` = ? where `id` = ?",
      "bindings": [
           "Noob",
           "2017-10-07 12:03:05",
           1
         ],
      "time": 3.36
}
]
}
```

So I thought about using the DB Facade.

```
Route::get('/cli', function(){
   DB::enableQueryLog();
$client = DB::select("update clients set first_name= 'Admin test' WHERE id=1");

   return response()->json([
       'client' => $client->first_name,
       'query' => DB::getQueryLog()
   ], 200);
});
```

and the result is

```
{
"client": [],
"query": [
{
"query": "update clients set first_name= 'Admin test' WHERE id=1",
"bindings": [],
"time": 3.2
}
]
}
```

This one ran only one query though it did not returned the Client instance. My question is, for a high traffic server which method or strategy is required to use? Is there any other better techniques or tricks in eloquent to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change  below query to eloquent

```
$client = DB::select("update clients set first_name= 'Admin test' WHERE id=1");
```

to

```
$data=['first_name'=>'Admin test'];
     Client::where('id', '=', 1)->update($data);
```

If i understood your question correctly then in first query you are selecting and then updating value so it will definitely execute two queries.
In your second method you are not fetching any think from db so it will be faster than first

Comment: Another short question. Is DB::select() faster than eloquent?

Comment: i dont think it will make  much difference in performance issue.in large join queries it might give faster performance .eloquent is much readability